# What do the numbers in an archive file mean?

Tags: c, unix

I'm using the `ar` command in Unix to create an archive file. In the resulting archive file each item in the file starts with something like

```
main.c/         1382296179  49083 12433 100660  1256      `
```

(followed by the contents of main.c)

What does the long list of numbers mean?

Thanks!

Comment: what modifiers did you use with your ar command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ar` format is not standardized, but, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29#File_header), the file header format can usually be expected to contain the following fields, which appear to match your example:

- File name
- File modification time
- Owner ID number
- Group ID number
- File mode in octal
- File size
- Grave accent (`) and linefeed